# Invoke an ant file from eclipse plugin jar

Tags: java, plugins, ant

I have a plugin named as AutomationPlug.jar 
It has an ant file (build.xml) inside it. i want to run the default target of this ant file using command prompt.
Is there any command to do the same? I tried to search on google but couldn't find any command like that. I do not want to extract the jar file.Please help?
Here is my plugin project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ant command is as below:

if your build filename is different that build.xml, give the build file name otherwise no required. If you want to run any different target otherthan default give the target name.

```
ant -buildfile <buildfilename> <targetname>
```

if everything is default just execute the ant command where build.xml is :

```
ant
```

Comment: my build.xml file is inside a jar file i.e AutomationPlug.jar file. I want to invoke it from there.

Comment: why you want to execute ant script inside the jar?

Comment: it is the project requirement. We will give only plugin to the client and the client will execute the build.xml file from that plugin using some command